# General Java class design for property with Collection which needs to listen for change

Tags: java, class, implementation

All,

Hopefully a simple question.  I am thinking of the best way to implement a class which holds a number of collections and HashMaps where the class needs to know about when they have been modified **outside of the class** - i.e. added/removed/changed items.  Each collection/hashmap needs to be exposed as a public getter in my class at the moment.

So my basic class looks like as follows...

```
public class MyClass {

    protected final HashMap<String, String> _values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    protected final ArrayList<MyOtherClass> _other = new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>();
    protected final ArrayList<MyOtherClass2> _other2 = new ArrayList<MyOtherClass2>();

    // ... implementation


    public HashMap<String, String> getValues() {
        return _values;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyOtherClass> getMyOtherClassList() {
        return _other;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyOtherClass2> getMyOtherClassList2() {
        return _other2;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        // build the content based on other/other2...
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // iterate through both collections to build content...
        // ...
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public getMyOtherClass {
    public String name;   // has getter and setter
    public String value;  // has getter and setter
}

public getMyOtherClass2 {
    public String name;   // has getter and setter
    public String value;  // has getter and setter
    public String somethingElse;  // has getter and setter
}
```

I want to add a key/value to the _values based on the length of the content i.e.-

```
_values.add("Length", getContent().length);
```

So the Length value is dynamic based on what gets added to the _other and _other2.

The problem with this is exposing the _values and _other with public getters is that anything outside the class can modify them.  The class will not know if items have been modified.

A couple of solutions I can think of is to make the collection/hashmap readonly - but this throws a runtime exception - if this was the case I'd like the compiler to indicate that they are read-only and throw an exception but I don't know if this is possible.

The other way would be to add a add/remove for each of the collections/maps and update the Length property accordingly - but again, if the values change in the MyOtherClass, MyClass  will still not know about it.

Alternatively write my own Hashmap/List/Collection to determine when items are added/removed, and possibly have a property change listener on the getMyOtherClass, getMyOtherClass2.

Any nice solutions to this?

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 1):

Overide the `map/list` implementations and insert a call-back into the `add/update/remove` methods that triggers an update function on the parent.
Also it's bad form to create references directly to the implementations - this is better (read up on polymorphism for reasoning):

```
private Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
private List<String> myList = new List<String>();
```

Comment: Dan, good spot.  I was manually copying and pasting in my example class so appologies.  But List<> is an interface too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can make use of some fundamentals of the [Observer](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) design pattern to have an Object "watching" the Maps and registering each change is made to them.

Create an object contains a Map and another object that contains a List, so since you have 1 map and 2 lists you'll have 3 of those "Observable" objects. Let's name the classes "ObservableMap" and "ObservableList". You can even create an abstract class "ObservableObject" and extend it with the previously mentioned classes.

These objects won't override the Map/List implementation, they'll only act as a wrapper by wrapping the methods you'll want to track to register the state and derive the call to modify the collection. For example, I'll post some code of the ObservableMap class (I'm instantiating the map with `<String,String>` but you can use generics here too if it suits you).

```
public Class ObservableMap extends ObservableObject{
    private Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    private Watcher observer = new Watcher();

    //Example of one of the wrapper methods (the other ones are like this one)
    public void putObject(String key, String value) {
        watcher.notifyPut(); //You can name the method the way you like and even pass
                             //the new key/value pair to identify what has been added.
        map.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

Here, the Watcher class is the one that registers the canges. It can either be a completely new Object (like in this case) or you can make an Interface and implement it in an existing class of yours to be able to set it as a watcher on your Observable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking.  If you are trying to track changes to attributes to two classes you may wish, as other people have mentioned implement the observer pattern and raise notifications in the set methods.  An alternative, that I have used successfully for implementing an undo mechanism is to use aspectJ or some other AOP (Aspect Orientated Programming) tool to intercept the set methods and perform the required notifications/updates that way.

Alternatively define an interface that only provides access to the getXXX operations and return those from your model, that way nothing can change the data.

Comment: Hi vickirk, I ideally want to expose the getters so that they could be modified outside of the class but the class exposing them knows about any changes made.  Gonna check the observer pattern.